# Does Blackberry support Android OS

Tags: android, blackberry

Is it possible to use Android OS for creating apps for Blackberry phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Android and Blackberry both use Java, they expose very different application APIs to developers.  So I don't think it is possible to run Android apps on a Blackberry - YET.  RIM has already announced that they are planning on supporting Android apps on the upcoming Blackberry Playbook tablet.

Comment: Repackaging tools available now: bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify. Develop BB apps on an Android machine? Or run Android OS on a BlackBerry device?

The former is plausible, albeit painful, and you'll still need an Android device or emulator to debug. Android machines (read: smartphones and tablets) are not, as a rule, content creation-friendly.

The latter is a epic hack, probably doable but nowhere near straightforward. And will surely void your warranty :)

Despite both platforms being Java-based, the runtime environments are quite different. Neither BB Java nor Android Java is Java ME compliant.

EDIT: Officially, it's not possible to run Android on a Blackberry device. They use their own operating system. Unofficially, who knows. But even if you manage, it will be a hack, not a supported configuration.

Converting apps from Android to BB - it will be more of a rewriting. Unless there's a well-isolated business layer (unlikely in the mobile software world), it will be a complete rewrite rather than conversion.

If you want to create BB apps, download Eclipse and Blackberry SDK, read the Getting started guide, and code away :) Knowing or learning the Java language would also help.

In addition, please note the difference between applications written "on" Android and "for" Android. "For" means "running on Android", "On" implies the actual coding/compiling was performed on an Android machine.

Comment: I am new to this area so I wasnt sure what device uses what OS. From your reply it seems that I cannot run Android OS on a Blackberry device. Is it possible to convert apps created on Android OS so that they would run on a BB? If I want to create BB apps what all steps do I need to follow?

Comment: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494777/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-(BlackBerry) might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Not all features of Android are supported in Blackberry OS 10, find the [link for the same](http://www.minemobile.com/mobileforum/discussion/41/non-supported-features-of-android-on-blackberry-os10#Item_2).